# codeception do not see field but the browser does (Chrome Driver)

Tags: codeception

I have a codeception test on angular 5 application. with HTML5 pretty url.
I am testing 2 steps forms.

```
url: /register/ fields: first_name,email,password  
when success redirect to:  
url: /personal-details/ fields: date_of_birth
```

First step goes perfectly fine. I test all the scenarios. when step one ends, the browser redirects with HTML5 redirection to `/personal-details/` as expected.
The problem is that codeception does not see #date_of_birth  even though it is existed.
To verify that, I puased the execution and in the console I run

```
  document.getElementById('date_of_birth')
```

and the field was found. it is on the page.

I though that it is related to the redirection, so I have added a special redirect in order to cause the first form to have the same problem, and it is working fine.

this is the error:

Test fields second step

```
 Test  tests\acceptance\FirstCest.php:testFieldsSecondStep
 Step  See element "#date_of_birth"
 Fail  Failed asserting that an array is not empty.
```

Scenario Steps:

What could possibly go wrong?
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe Codeception checks if element exists before the page is fully loaded.
Try to use [waitForElement](https://codeception.com/docs/modules/WebDriver#waitForElement) instead of seeElement

```
$I->waitForElement('#date_of_birth', 10);
```

Answer (score 1):

I came across this post with a similar issue. For (in my opinion) no valid reason I got the message

"*Failed asserting that an array is not empty.*"

when using **$I->canSeeElement()** or **$I->canSeeElementInDom()**. In my case, I was not dealing with elements that are loaded asynchronously, those elements were present.

This is what my code looked like:

```
$I->canSeeElementInDOM('//*[@id="MyId"]//input[@name="myCheckbox"][not(@checked)]');
```

Using the following syntax fixed the problem:

```
$I->canSeeElementInDOM('//*[@id="MyId"]//input[@name="myCheckbox" and not(@checked)]');
```

Hope this helps someone too.